# What does this float formula mean?

Tags: c++, floating-point

OK, I was given a formula to determine a float value between 0.0 and 1.0 using i and j (coordinates of a value in a 2D array).  I simply want to know exactly what this formula does.  It makes no sense to me.  I have implemented it in its own function where the int values of i and j are passed as parameters.  Can someone provide an explanation?  I don't HAVE to understand it, as he gave it to us just to use as is, but I really want to know.

```
float col = float (((i & 0x08) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x08) == 0));
```

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: You can usually figure out a complex expression by breaking it down into its component parts.  Which part don't you understand?

Comment: This one is actually not obvious at all. I can't figure it out myself after 2 min. So I'll +1 for it.

Comment: The right hand side of the expression.  What is float() itself doing, first of all.  Then, I don't understand what (i & 0x08) does. I've never seen that before.  I know that & is a reference operator, but is it referencing 0x08?  What is 0x08?

Comment: In this case, `&` is the [bitwise AND operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). `0x08` is a hexadecimal value which is just the number `8`.

Comment: @Mysticial: Literally **what** it does is trivial; **why** it does it, I have no idea.  I imagine it would be clearer with context.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yeah, I can't figure out the **why** or the "big picture" **what** is.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, that helps @Mysticial.  Now, is there a built in c++ float function that takes values like that?  How does it recognize that 0x08 is hexadecimal in this case, and not just some numbers surrounding a non-existent variable 'x'?

Comment: @TheRationalist: Because that's part of the language. `0x...` denotes a hexadecimal literal.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : It's simply being used in a program to determine a floating point number that's between 0.0 and 1.0.  That number is then going to be converted to an integer between 0 and 255 to be used in a ppm file output.

Comment: @TheRationalist: Oh, I understand that.  but `i` and `j` must have some significance, and there must be some importance to the 4th bit of each that would explain **why** this expression is being used.

Comment: It does not determine a number between `0` and `1`. It simply can't, without even knowing what `i` and `j` are you can say that. `col` will either be `1` OR `0`, depending on `i` and `j` supplied.

Comment: @Mysticial - Thanks a lot for clearing most of that up for me.  If you put all your information as an answer to this question, I'll mark it as the answer.  I still don't understand how the function call float() works.

Comment: It's not a function, it's explicit type conversion.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: I said in the OP that i and j will be integers (coordinates in a 2D array to be exact).  Quoted directly from the assignment:  Write a program that generates a w x h ppm file containing the resulting rasterized image when you set the color of the pixel (i,j) with the value col as in: <insert above formula here>

Comment: @PetrBudnik:  Thank you. That's exactly the last thing I needed to know.

Comment: I know `i` and `j` are integers, you cannot do bitwise operations on `float` directly. The point is, the logic lies within you 2D array. People explained below what this operation does. Why you need this operation depends on the program logic. You should accept one of the answers below, by the way.

Comment: The intent, which you'd probably see if you implemented it, is to draw a chessboard (assuming width and height are 64). In fact, the expression could have been written, perhaps no less mysteriously, as  `((i^j)&8)/8.0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result, if plotted with `i,j` as the x,y coordinates, will be a checkerboard with squares of 8x8 pixels.

The `i & 0x08` and `j & 0x08` are just testing a single bit of each axis. That bit will change state every 8 pixels.

The `== 0` will convert each result to a boolean, which evaluates to either a 0 or 1. It also inverts the result, but I don't think that's relevant in the overall formula.

The `^` exclusive-or operator will return 0 if the two are the same, or 1 if they're different. That's how you get the checkerboard - the result alternates each time either `i` or `j` crosses a boundary.

Comment: @mvp no, and it appears I can't read either. Looking back over the comments to the original question, it seems someone reached the same conclusion 43 minutes before I did.

Comment: I see - it is by @rici. Still, you cared to actually type this great answer here.

Comment: @mvp, thanks for the compliment. I always strive to leave great answers but some attempts are more successful than others. Lots of practice helps, I've been at this for 5 years now. You might find this interesting: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of Boolean and [bitwise boolean operators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html) here.. Let me try to answer in parts.. 
Lets first split into pieces

`A:(i & 0x08)`
Performing bitwise and on i - basically and is performed on each bit of i and 0x08( 1000 in binary)

`B:A==0`
Check if the bitwise and is false for EVERY BIT
**Basically checks if the 4th bit from the last is 0**

`C: B ^ B'`
Bitwise XOR- returns 1 if one of them and not both of them is true (bitwise)

`D:float(C)`
Easy one, casts C to float.

End result - No idea..

Answer (score 1):

```
float col = float (((i & 0x08) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x08) == 0));
```

`& 0x08` does a bitwise and with 8, which means it extracts the 4th least signficant bit (1 is the least, then 2, 4, 8) from the numbers `i` and `j`.  The `^` is an exclusive OR operation: if both bits are the same the result is 0, if they differ the result is 1.  That's promoted to a `float` by the outside `= float(...)`, so `col` becomes `0.0` if `i` and `j` are the same, but `1.0` if they differ.

Why might it be useful?  That depends on what `i` and `j` are.  Presumably, the 4th bit encodes some specific condition or flag (a boolean), for example: whether a person is male or female.  The `&` operation extracts that, then the `^` says "do they differ?".  Why might you want a boolean expression converted to a float?  Not many good reasons to be honest - you can always let the conversion be done implicitly at the place it's used as in (assuming male/female):

```
bool hetero = i & 0x08 ^ j & 0x08;
float estimated_children_from_coupling = 1.3 * hetero;  // same as hetero ? 1.3 : 0;
```

Comment: Note: that's **not** a C-style cast (that would be `(float)blah`).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: ah true... C's rusty.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In short, "col = 1.0" if "i" OR "j" is equal to 0x08 (decimal 8).

(i & 0x08): not zero if "i == 0x08", zero otherwise
(i & 0x08) == 0: 1/true if "i != 0x08", 0/false if "i == 0x08"
same for "j"

Hence the "exclusive or" (^ operator) of the 2 sides will be true of either of them is true, but not both, which happens when i OR j is 0x08.

Finally, it casts the result to float for whatever the reason.